# Campus Tour iPhone App

Tags: iphone

I am I want to develop a Campus Map application on iPhone. I am searching for a way to figure out how to sync Current Location from Maps with my campus map. Or is there any other approach for building this app ? 
Suggest some good websites/ blogs/ groups working on something similar so that I can get information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLLocationManager` will let you put a pin on your map, check heading, etc.

http://www.mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. Pretty neat tutorial. But I am not able to download the zip file from github.

Answer (score 0):

what you look for is the map overlay - check out this tutorial:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJxdCe9CNYg